# In dxdatagrid how to hide add row button dynamically?

Tags: angular, typescript, dx-data-grid

In our Angular application, we have used dx data grid to display records. We have used batch mode. I want to hide add row button dynamically.

When we click on the add button, a new row will come to enter data. Then I want either the button to be disabled or hidden if the record is not saved.

Please see my settings

```cs
public setGridPropertiesWithBatchMode(grid: any) {          
    grid.option({    
                allowColumnResizing: true,            
                headerFilter: {
                    visible: true
                },
                hoverStateEnabled: true,
                loadPanel: {
                    enabled: false
                },            

                editing: {
                    allowAdding: true,
                    allowUpdating: true,
                    mode: 'batch'
                },

                rowAlternationEnabled: true
     });
}
```

Any one please help me to resolve this issue.